# How to stop framebreaker but allow browsing

Tags: javascript

Thank you for your great code on how to stop a framebreaker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prevent_bust = 0  
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ }  
    setInterval(function() {  
      if (prevent_bust > 0) {  
        prevent_bust -= 2  
        window.top.location = 'http://server-which-responds-with-204.com'  
      }  
    }, 1)  
</script>
```

When I incorporate this into my links page it treats every link as a framebreaker because each link must be surfed one after another.

I find if I change this line if (prevent_bust > 0) {  to  if (prevent_bust > 1) { then it lets me continue surfing but then it no longer catches the actual links that are frame breakers.

What I think I need is a way to cancel the onbeforeunload event so it only activates when the real framebreakers are around.

I hope you can help me.  I would be happy to pay you something for your trouble.

I can be contacted on pbirch31@gmail or on facebook under Paul Australia

Comment: I was working with onbeforeunload event. Fortunately you cannot cancel or prevent default for the event(It is a security issue). Anyway if you return null it will stop the execution of the callback function in Chrome.
window.onbeforeunload = function() { prevent_bust++ 
return null;}
alternatively you can call an absent property to deliberately crash the callback execution. 
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { prevent_bust++;
e.defaultPrevented;}.
This will stop the execution of the callback. Hope part of it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately it doesn't help.  It seems a conundrum very difficult to find an answer to.

Comment: This code above is so close to what I need.  The problem is that it treats all links as a framebreaker.  When the user clicks Next link, this script thinks it is a framebreaker trying to break out of the frame instead of letting another link be loaded into the frame.  Surely there must be an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be less obnxious: modify all the links to open 
in a new tab or window.

No onBeforeUnload and no setInterval polling every 1 ms.

Requires jQuery.

```
<script>
$('a').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('target')='_blank';
});
</script>
```

Comment: this is a for a manual surfing site.  Sorry I should have made myself a little clearer.  The user starts off on a main page of links and clicks the first link....the a New window opens with 2 frames the top frame has the timer and the bottom frame displays the page for the link they clicked.

Comment: A user/surfer could surf 1000 links..it would be too hard to open a new page for every link they view.  Also not very practical.  Thanks for your reply though.